# remove less than 4 character words(python)

Tags: python

```
with open('text.txt','r') as f:
    for i in f:
        trantab = str.maketrans({key: None for key in string.punctuation})
        j = i.translate(trantab)
        result1.append(j)
shortword = re.compile(r'\W*\b\w{1,4}\b')
shortword.sub('', result1)
f = result1
```

and the error is:

```
  line 13, in shortword.sub('', result1)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: You need to provide more information, What you wanna do!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming each word is on an individual line, if not you will have to breakdown `content` with `.split()`

```
with open('something.txt') as f:
    content = [line.strip() for line in f]

res = list(filter(lambda x: len(x) >= 4, content))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you're trying to [].sub() an array...

I Solved what u need with this script:

```
import re

t = []
t.append("THIS IS A SIMPLE DUMMY TEXT")
t.append("ANOTHER INDEX BLA BLA")

for i in t: 
    shortword = re.compile(r'\W*\b\w{1,4}\b')
    t = shortword.sub('', str(t))

print(t)
```

You just need to assign shortword.sub('', result1) to result1 and make sure to use str():

```
result1 = shortword.sub('', str(result1))
```

I believe that will do for you!